# Adobe Creative SDK Files Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sdk, adobe, creative-cloud

I am trying to rewrite the code below in Swift. However in Swift the *itemSelections* says it must be a type of [AnyObject]. Is there a way to get around this? Thanks

**Adobe Code**

```
- (void)showFileChooser {

[[AdobeUXAssetBrowser sharedBrowser] popupFileBrowser:^(AdobeSelectionAssetArray *itemSelections) {
NSLog(@"Selected a file");
for(id item in itemSelections) {

AdobeAsset *it = ((AdobeSelectionAsset *)item).selectedItem;

NSLog(@"File name %@", it.name);
}
...
```

**Swift Conversion**

```
AdobeUXAssetBrowser.sharedBrowser().popupFileBrowser({ (itemSelections:[AnyObject]!) -> Void in
```

Comment: I don't have the Adobe Creative SDK, but it seems to be that you can simply apply the solution to your previous question: `for item in itemSelections as [AdobeSelectionAsset]` { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
AdobeUXAssetBrowser.sharedBrowser().popupFileBrowser({ (itemSelections) in
    if let itemSelectionsAssets = itemSelections as? [AdobeSelectionAsset] {
        for itemSelectionAsset in itemSelectionsAssets {
            let item = itemSelectionAsset.selectedItem
            println("File name: \(item.name)")
        }
    }
}
```